# Upload Files In Storage

Tags: laravel, forms, file-upload, storage, crud

There is a table house. It has four columns (where the path to the downloaded file should be saved). I tried to download one file in the controller for the test, but it did not appear in the database

```php
 $this->validate($request, [
                      'passport' => 'required'
        ]);

        $homes = Houses::query()->create([
                
                'passport' => $request->get('passport')
            ]
        );
     
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:docs,txt,doc,xls,pdf,docx, docm,rtf,xps,xml|max:4098'
        ]);

        $fileModel = new File;

        if ($request->file()) {
            $fileName = time() . '_' . $request->file - getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $request->file('passport')->storeAs('passport_house', $fileName, 'public');

            $fileModel->name = time() . '_' . $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
            $fileModel->save();
        }


        return redirect()->route('homes.index');
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You did it right but you have some Typo. Please check below code.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'passport' => 'required'
]);

$homes = Houses::query()->create([
  'passport' => $request->get('passport')
]);

$request->validate([
  'file' => 'required|mimes:docs,txt,doc,xls,pdf,docx, docm,rtf,xps,xml|max:4098'
]);

$fileModel = new File;

if ($request->has('file')) {
   $file = $request->file;

   $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $filename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        

   $fileName = time() . '_' . $filename.'.'.$ext;
   $filePath = $file->storeAs('passport_house', $fileName, 'public');

   $fileModel->name = $fileName;
   $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
   $fileModel->save();
}

return redirect()->route('homes.index');
}
```

Comment: No - the page is still reloaded without adding it to the database, and the file is also not loaded
As I understand it, I have to output on the view itself as `<input type="file" name="passport" />`? @Vinod Patidar

Comment: Your file is stored in folder ?

Comment: No, and the folder has not been created either. @Vinod Patidar

Comment: I have updated above code and make sure your folder have read and write permission.

Comment: No, everything is the same as it was, the page just reloads. Is it possible to reduce my code so that a folder with a home is just created and files are already attached to it? I will have a problem most likely with the fact that the card at home has 4 fields for loading. Even if I somehow make this function, I would like to make it so that in the future I can update the files, and in case of moving to another hosting, have files for each house in one folder(storage/app/public/ house/id) and it already contains four catalogs, a passport, reports, contracts, meetings @Vidon Patidar